# How can I get the list of properties that MSBuild was invoked with?

Tags: command-line, msbuild, properties

Given this command:

```
MSBuild.exe build.xml /p:Configuration=Live /p:UseMerge=true /p:EnableUpdateable=false
```

how can I form a string like this in my build script:

```
UseMerge=true;EnableUpdateable=true
```

where I might **not** know which properties were used at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you going to do with the list?

There's no built in "properties that came via the commandline" thing a la splatting in PowerShell 2.0

Remember properties can come from environment variables and/or other scripts.

Also, you stripped on of the params out in your example.

In general, if one is trying to chain to another command, one uses defaulting (`Condition`s on  elements in `PropertyGroup`s) and validation (`Message`s `Condition`al on presence of options) and then either create a new property or embed the params you want to pass into a string.

Here's hoping someone has a nice neat example of a more general way to do this but I doubt it.

As covered in http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/extending-msbuild/ one can dump out the parameters passed by doing `/v:diag` on the commandline (but that's obviously not what you're after).

Have a look in the Common.targets files - you'll find lots of cases of chaininign involving manaully building up lists to pass onto subservient tasks.

Comment: "There's no built in "properties that came via the commandline" thing a la splatting in PowerShell 2.0"

Ok, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @michielvoo: [Not 100% sure whether you're serious about that - if you are, maybe you should have FizzBinned and I could have made it that brief in the first place!] Not sure why I thought that would have meaning for anyone that doesnt listen to PowerScripting. BTW If you dont have it already, get the Inside MSBuild book - its fantastic.